# How to install Oracle Database on MacOS

Tags: java, database, oracle, macos

I have a MackBook Pro with EL Capitan. And I want to install Oracle DataBase on it.
Can I install it directly?

I found this instruction https://dimitrisli.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/how-to-install-oracle-database-on-mac-os-any-version/

But it is an old instruction. And I couldn't managed to connect to DB following this instruction.

Also I have a Parallels Desktop App and Windows installed on it.
I've installed Oracle DB there. But I can't connect from macOS's SQL Developer App to Oracle DB witch is installed on Windows in Parallels Desktop App.

Is there any possibility to install Oracle DB directly on my Mac or connect from Mac to Windows's Oracle DB?

Comment: Wrong forum, this is for programming questions, not for how to install software on your computer.

Comment: How about [Database Virtual Box Appliance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html) ?

Comment: How to connect from Mac's SQL Developer to Database Installed on Linux in Virtual Box?